# Need an approach for mounting turrets

Tags: c++, 3d, directx11, 3d-meshes

I'm working on a game with the ability to customize the type of turrets on your starship. My question is how would I go about positioning the turret mesh at the hardpoint locations. Do I need to manually save a position in 3d space? Could I use bones to store the hardpoint locations? Whats the best approach here?

Comment: Model bones associated with the 3D model are probably the best approach.

Comment: It sounds like you have two workable solutions. Which one do you prefer? What happens when you try applying it? Do you run into any specific problems that we can help you solve?